# Mysql not starting with changed datadir

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I was looking for a way to store my mysql databases on a different partition than the default installation. I found [this link](http://arcoleo.org/dsawiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Move%20MySQL%20Databases%20to%20Another%20Partition%20or%20Drive) and followed the steps.

However, after having changed the line `datadir = /var/lib/mysql` in `my.cnf` to `datadir = /storage/mysql-data`, I find myself unable to start the mysql service again:

```
pieter@foxbox:~$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

When I change the `datadir` back to the standard value, it *does* work again. Why? What is the problem with the solution in the link?

*I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, 32bit*

Answer (score 0):

Did you move all files from /var/lib/mysql to /storage/mysql-data before starting mysql ? Also, check that the permissions of the new directory are the same as those of /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Only the folders corresponding to databases.